# Return a fake value from external DLL using C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, testing, automation

We are working on three layer architecture (UI - **Library1** - **Library2** -> Hardware) developed in C# , but I wanted to test the code which I have implemented in **library1**, but the problem we do not have access to hardware (various reasons) but we can access **library2**.

My question is can I return a fake value from library2 like if the functionality is implemented to test the hardware connection and when ever we call that library2 function return true or any related default return parameter that is accessed from library1?

I am using VS2010.

Comment: You will want to look into mocking. As a general rule, you should try to never make any external calls that rely on things such as hardware, data, etc...

Comment: @gmiley Mocking ?, sorry i am new to all these things can you please help me with the links or approach that will guide me through it. Couple of examples can be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of examples you can find by doing a google search on: C# Mocking. I tend to write my own mock classes and implement an ObjectFactory that I can use to specifically instantiate mock classes in tests, but otherwise default to the real class.

For example: If I wanted to use System.Net.WebRequest I would first create my common interface - IWebRequest that exposes .Timeout, .UploadString, and any others I might use in my application.

Then I would create my implementation class using that interface. Inside the implementation of say, .UploadString, I would create an instance of the real System.Net.WebRequest class and call its .UploadString.

In the mock class, implement it using the IWebRequest interface, just like the real wrapper class, but when you implement the .UploadString method, instead just have it return a hardcoded response. You can put these mock classes in their own "Mocks" library that is only included in your test projects.

To get all this to run you will need your ObjectFactory which is included in both your regular code projects and your unit test projects. You will have static functions with return types of your interfaces (IWebRequest) that check if a classes has been manually specified. If it hasn't it returns an instance of the default "real" implementation.

In your test you would access the ObjectFactory and manually set that you want to use a specific mock class and when your real code runs it instantiates that instead of your real class.

Keep in mind, like I said, there are a lot of examples out there, and even full implementations of mocking frameworks that you can use. Just take a look on google.

Answer (score 0):

Although there are many different frameworks for providing this function, I would recommend just sticking with the built-in VS.net framework as described here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx

Comment: This is useful for VS2012 and above , but i was looking for VS2010 . thanks for the reply anyhow.